# Twitter Bootstrap Tabs Jump to Top when changing Tab

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 tabs. With different heights, and on top of the tabs I have a Row.

As in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdawood1991/8sdov3hu/).

The problem I am having is that the page jumps to the Top when changing from a tab with greater height to a tab with less height.

I am using Bootstrap Tabs.

I have tried removing the `data-toggle="tab"` from

```
<li><a href="#caseTab" data-toggle="tab">Case</a></li>
```

To

```
<li><a href="#caseTab">Case</a></li>
```

And loading the Tab using jQuery:

```
$('.nav-tabs li a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
        return false;
    });
```

And also tried to return false according to Suggestions Online of `return false;`

[Here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-tabs-page-jumps-to-top-when-tab-changes):

Could someone help me fix this?

Comment: Of course it will jumping because of vertical scrollbar appears because of content goes long than window height.

Answer (score 1):

You can add on css `.tab-content{min-height: 950px;}`
Or you can set min-height from biggest block.

Comment: Tried that if I set a min-height. e.g. 300px, I will have a large blank space at the bottom of my smaller Tab.

Answer (score 0):

Add a common min-height to the tabs to ensure that all the tabs have equal height. This will prevent your page from jumping around when switching tabs.

To find the best min-height value, just check the height, say XXpx of your longest tab and use that value as the common min-height value: `min-height: XXpx;` for all the tabs.

Comment: There is a jsfiddle in my Question

Comment: And if I set a min-height. e.g. 300px, I will have a large blank space at the bottom of my smaller Tab.

Comment: Of cousre, there is no other way to fix. you can try from same-height js plugin